# Is there any objection to nest a NextJS project in another NextJS project?

Tags: next.js

I have a big NextJS project (let's say its Twitter). I have to build a small moderation tool for it, and I'd like to do it using NextJS.

I know the existance of workspaces, but I don't want to bother with it if it is not needed.

Is there any objective reason why I shouldn't nest the moderation tool inside the big project like this ?

```
_moderationtool
  src
  public
  next.config.js
  tsconfig.js
  package.json
common_code_i_use_inboth
  types.ts
src
public
next.config.js
tsconfig.js
package.json
```

I had issues with typescript typechecking _moderationtool files, but I added the directory into tsconfig.exclude and now it is fine